# Section header for references shows wrong number

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, numbering, titlesec

So I downloaded a nice looking article template which has a custom look for section titles. But now the number next to the References header is the same as that of the last section.

How do I fix this? Showing no number at all has my preference, but showing the correct section number is fine too.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}% Allows customization of titles
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering{\Roman{section}.}}{}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Problem description}

Blah blah blah.
\subsection{Another section}

Another section.
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{ref}
  some reference.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}` to change the format of unnumbered sections (here: the bibliography).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering{\Roman{section}.}}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Problem description}

Blah blah blah.
\subsection{Another section}

Another section.
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{ref}
  some reference.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, cool output image. How did you do that, just a screenshot or can StackExchange interpret LaTeX?

Comment: @Maarten Just a cropped screenshot.